# chef only_if attribute equals true

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, lwrp

**Problem:** I have a chef statement that should only run if the attribute is "true".  But it runs every time.

**Expected Behavior:**  When `default[:QuickBase_Legacy_Stack][:dotNetFx4_Install] = "false"` dotnet4 should not be installed.

**Actual Behavior:** No matter what the attribute is set to, it installs dotnet4.

**My code:**

attribute file:

```
default[:QuickBase_Legacy_Stack][:dotNetFx4_Install] = "false"
```

recipe file:

```
windows_package "dotnet4" do
    only_if node[:QuickBase_Legacy_Stack][:dotNetFx4_Install]=='true'
    source "#{node[:QuickBase_Legacy_Stack][:dotNetFx4_URL]}"
    installer_type :custom
    action :install
    options "/quiet /log C:\\chef\\installLog4.txt /norestart /skipmsuinstall"
end
```

Comment: I really like the format of your question. You clearly identified the problem, given outcome, and desired outcome. You must be an engineer :)

Comment: Yes I am, perhaps you can reward it with an upvote... :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Guards](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_common.html#guards) that run Ruby must be enclosed in a block `{}` otherwise Chef will try to run the string in the default interpreter (usually bash).

```
windows_package "dotnet4" do
    only_if        { node[:QuickBase_Legacy_Stack][:dotNetFx4_Install] == 'true' }
    source         node[:QuickBase_Legacy_Stack][:dotNetFx4_URL]
    installer_type :custom
    action         :install
    options        "/quiet /log C:\\chef\\installLog4.txt /norestart /skipmsuinstall"
end
```

Check if you need boolean `true` instead of `"true"`

Also, use the plain variable name (for `source`) unless you need to interpolate other data with the string quoting.

Answer (score 8):

That is a Ruby conditional, so you need to use a block for your `not_if`:

```
only_if { node[:QuickBase_Legacy_Stack][:dotNetFx4_Install]=='true' }
```

(Please take note of the added `{}`). You can also use the `do..end` syntax for multiline conditions:

```
only_if do
  node[:QuickBase_Legacy_Stack][:dotNetFx4_Install]=='true'
end
```

Finally, please make sure your value is the String `"true"` and not the value `true` (see the difference). In Ruby, `true` is a boolean (just like `false`), but `"true"` is a string (just like `"foo"`) Checking if `true` == `"true"` will return `false`.

Comment: I am having a similar issue.. I have `"sync_db": "true"` in json config and in my chef recipe I cannot get it to work unless I check if  `only_if { sub_site['sync_db'] != nil }` and remove it from attributes.  `only_if { sub_site['sync_db'] == "true"}` or `true` does not work. Any idea?